# Pass variable in URL via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

This is a piece of JavaScript code using jQuery Datatables.

I want to pass the variable `ident` (it equals `2` in the example below) in the URL via Ajax, see below:

```
ajax: "staff2.php?userid='+ ident +'"
```

It's not passing properly. However replacing `'+ ident +'` with `2` works.

So what is wrong with that line?

```
var ident = '2';


var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples
$(document).ready(function() {
    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
        ajax: "staff2.php?userid='+ ident +'",
        table: "#building",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        fields: [ {
                label: "",
                name: "building"
            }
        ]
    } );
    // Activate an inline edit on click of a table cell
$('#building').on( 'click', 'tbody td', function () {
    editor.inline( this );
} );
    $('#building').DataTable( {
        //dom: "Tfrtip",
        "searching": false,
        "bInfo" : false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bSort": false,
        "bVisible": false,
        ajax: "staff2.php?userid='+ ident +'",
        columns: [
            { data: null, defaultContent: '', orderable: false },
            { data: "building" },           
        ],
        order: [ 1, 'asc' ],
        tableTools: {
            sRowSelect: "os",
            sRowSelector: 'td:first-child',
            aButtons: [
                { sExtends: "editor_create", editor: editor },
                { sExtends: "editor_edit",   editor: editor },
                { sExtends: "editor_remove", editor: editor }
            ]
        }
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're constructing URL incorrectly.

Replace:

```
ajax: "staff2.php?userid='+ ident +'",
```

with

```
ajax: "staff2.php?userid=" + ident,
```

If `ident` contains not only numbers, you also need to encode it with [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) as `encodeURIComponent(ident)` to correctly escape special characters.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your string concatenation.
Replace this line:

```
ajax: "staff2.php?userid='+ ident +'",
```

With this:

```
ajax: "staff2.php?userid=" + ident,
```

Comment: If `ident` equals to `2`, your code produces URL `staff2.php?userid='2'`, which is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that @Gyrocode. Code adjusted accordingly.